# Passing Headers Through to mod_jk

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-jk

Apache 2.2.24
mod_jk 1.2.37

I'm trying to pass the siteminder username through to Tomcat which is configured with mod_jk.  The siteminder username is available a request header named "SM_USER".

When I hard code a value using the environment variable JK_REMOTE_USER(http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html), mod_jk picks it up and passes it through to Tomcat.

e.g.(works with static username)
SetEnv JK_REMOTE_USER "nickw"

However, I want to take the SM_USER header and pass it through dynamically.

e.g.(user passed through is null)
SetEnvIfNoCase SM_USER ^[a-z].* JK_REMOTE_USER

Is there an obvious problem with the config I'm using?  Is the SetEnvIfNoCase processing occuring after the call to mod_jk?  Or is there another simpler way that would accomplish the same thing?